# Difference between "+" and "~"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

What is the main difference between `$('div + p')` and `$('div ~ p')`.

If i have something like this

```
<div class="active"></div>
<p class="pactive"></p>
```

Returning the same value.

Comment: [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) and  [Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

Comment: They have a [horrible habit](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) of hiding this sort of information [in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

Comment: Why not just look in the documentation ? There's no secret here !

Comment: It is fine for the question to be asked here as Stackoverflow is for many developers the first port of call.

Comment: @MrGray - And that succinctly sums up all that is wrong with this industry. First port of call should be some rational thought ("hmm, maybe that level of information is documented somewhere") not "I wonder if someone has the time to spoon-feed me information"

Comment: No, just be helpful, being otherwise is what is wrong.

Comment: @MrGray No, we don't need more trivial questions that are already answered both on SO and in the canonical documentation.

Comment: @MrGray, congratulations. You're part of the problem, not of the solution.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is a knowledge base and any question that fits the format is fine, I don't want to get personal about it, if the question has already been asked and answered on SO then flag it, don't attack me for my opinion.

Comment: @MrGray, we aim to be the *best* repository of knowledge around, and copy-pasting documentation back at questioners does not really achieve that goal, especially now that we're flooded with no-research questions all day long. I'm not getting "personal" here, but your comment is just wrong, and it would be a pity if users were to take it as the community's stance. If you don't want others to challenge your opinions, maybe you should not post them in comments.

Comment: @jamiec Sometimes what may look like easy to find information might not be so. He asked a valid question is all I am saying and we can't possibly know what thoughts he did or didn't have, to presume otherwise is actually not helpful, flagging the question as a duplicate is helpful.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have no problem people challenging my opinions, just wish it was done in a more constructive fashion. I agree that we are trying to make this a good place for knowledge but not everyone is at the same level so the questions being asked may be from relative naivety and we should be sensitive to that or people won't come back here.

Comment: While we can hopefully agree that trivial questions should be researched first, asked later - the fact is that this question has already been asked and if there is an existing answer, point the OP there, and move on. There are some users who, unlike Mr Gray, consider even flagging questions as dupes to be unhelpful - for reasons I cannot comprehend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<div class="active"></div>
<p class="pactive"></p>
<div></div>
<p></p>
<div></div>
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

`$("div.active + p")` will only select the `p` with class `pactive`(ie. `p` next to the `div`, same as `$(div).next();`)

> Result:

```
<p class="pactive"></p>
```

where as `$("div.active ~ p")` will select all the sibling `p`s which will come after the `div.active` only.If any `p` element is there before `div.active` it wont select that `p`.

> Result:

```
<p class="pactive"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: @downvoter : may i know why you have down voted?anything wrong with the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Take an example

`div + p`

> Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

`p ~ ul`

> Selects every `<ul>` element that are preceded by a `<p>` element **and** have the same parent element.

Check out the **[CSS REFERENCE Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/)**

Comment: You should provide a reference (source) link when marking text like that.

Comment: Well I actually misunderstood your comment,I thought you wanted me to provide some kind of code with a refering to some jsfiddle link. Thanks for the suggestion, I have made the update

Comment: No, that is not necessary. But text marked like that means you have copied it from somewhere. If you haven't copyied it from the question you really should provide a source. +1 for doing so

Comment: sure..I ll keep it in mind from next time :)

Answer (score 1):

**X + Y**

```
ul + p {
   color: red;
}
```

This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text.

**X ~ Y**

```
ul ~ p {
   color: red;
}
```

This sibling combinator is similar to X + Y, however, it's less strict. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above, any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.

**[For Reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)**

Comment: "In this case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text." **No.** Only a paragraph that directly follows an unordered list will have this rule applied.

Comment: "It will select, referring to our example above, any p elements, as long as they follow a ul." Again, **no.** It will select all `p` element that come after a ul in the markup **and** that share the same parent element.